# When translating a site into multiple languages, can we redirect our original language URLs to include the language identifier and maintain SEO?

Tags: seo, url, internationalization, language, localization

We're in the process of localising our website into FR, DE and ES. As part of the current design, all URLs in the website will include the locale e.g. `example.com/fr` or `example.com/es`.

Our developer has also enforced this for the default language EN, so all our existing URLs will redirect from `example.com/page_1` to `example.com/en/page_1`

Is this good practice? I'm concerned about the SEO impact.

Answer (score 1):

If your developer is using a 301 Redirect then this is the best practice.

Google guideline (and I guess guideline from other search engines) is simple on this matter. When you are moving a URL and want to maintain its SEO value implement a 301 Redirect when the change is permanent.

[Source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Using a 301 redirect for this is indeed the correct way to do.

Should you "move" your EN site from `example.com` to `example.com/EN`? Probably not - there's nothing to gain from doing this, it's perfectly fine to have the main language in your main domain (not only that but people probably expect to).